# Worksheet_SelectionChange() not firing on a specific PC

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I have *.xlm* file shared in network.
It work fine for another users, on other PCs, but on a specific PC some macros from this file works, but `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` not working.

What else should I do on this PC?

Excel 2019

- *Code in right place (Sheet1)*
- *Can't create new file and move code to it. (to much another code + forms)*
- *In the immediate window:*
  *`?Application.EnableEvents True`*

UPD: Just test:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MsgBox "test"
End Sub
```

not working too.

And found one very strange thing:

```
Sub test()
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

give error:

```
Run-time error '429':
ActiveX component can't create object
```

in Immediate

```
?Application.EnableEvents
True
```

ok

- Add-ins empty (by default)
- References under password

and one else, problem only with specific workbook on specific PC and problem with Events. Another WB works on this PC. This WB work on another PC.
Crazy.

Comment: and the trust center settings, this machine / user may have macros disabled.  Create a a new workbook with just a greeting message box on the workbook_open, very simple code on its own, see if macros are working ?

Comment: macros works, but event - not working. 'Trust center settings' -> 'macro settings' the same (by default).
Add-ins not check yet...(not at this PC now) but on another PC works without any add-ins

Comment: just now on this PC. In new Workbook `Worksheet_SelectionChange` works. 
In needed wb - not work, and one else 
*Sub test()
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub*
make error '429' ActiveX component can't create oject
References under passwod (

Comment: How do you subscribe to the `SelectionChange` event? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
....
End Sub
but it's not my code. I need that it work on this PC.